# Get number of character selected in a multiline textbox in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, multiline

Hai Guys,
 I have a multiline textbox and I have set **MaxLength="160"** ,also i have a **label indicating number of characters remaining**.... Now i want to get the number of characters selected by the user he may delete it and i have to add to the count representing total number of characters left inside that label..... I want this to be done in the **Text_Changed event** of the textbox

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you trying to do this on the client?  The TextChanged event is a server-side event.

Comment: The selected text information does not go server side. Using the technologies you indicated, excluding any kind of client side scripting, what you're asking is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this client side use javascript, a solution for that is [shown here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/JavaScript/Q_21269907.html). To do it in a server side event handler, just get the length of the string, by the time your page has been posted back to the server the highlight has gone.